# How to handle divide by zero in Sum() with efcore

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I'm struggling with an error affecting a system we used for Insights for our customers. The code is as follows:

```
Insights MyInsights = new Insights();
MyInsights.UnpostedInvoiceValue = DatabaseContext.Invoice
.Where(z => z.OwnedBy.TenantId == CurrentTenant.TenantId && z.Posted == false)
.Sum(x => x.Items.Sum(y =>(y.PricePerUnit  /  y.ExchangeRate) * y.Quantity / y.Units.PriceFactor));
```

The issue is when ".ExchangeRate" or "y.Units.PriceFactor" is 0(Zero), as we all a divide by zero isn't possible, and so we get an exception for this.

As this system is multi-tenanted, this seems to affect all tenants even when just one has a 0(Zero) in their data. I would have expected this not to be the case because we have a Where clause which checks the Tenant Id.

The SQL generated is as follows:

```
SELECT (
 SELECT SUM((([y].[PricePerUnit] / [y].[ExchangeRate]) * [y].[Quantity]) / [y.Units].[PriceFactor])
 FROM [InvoiceItem] AS [y]
 LEFT JOIN [Units] AS [y.Units] ON [y].[UnitsId] = [y.Units].[UnitsId]
WHERE [z].[InvoiceId] = [y].[InvoiceId]
)
 FROM [Invoice] AS [z]
 WHERE ([z].[OwnedByTenantId] = @__CurrentTenant_TenantId_0) AND ([z].[Posted] = 0)
```

The exception returned is:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Divide by zero error encountered.'
```

I see this issue being two-fold:

1. I don't understand why this is affecting all tenants when only one has a 0(Zero) in their data.
2. Ideally, if a 0(Zero) exists in one of those fields, Sum() should return 0, but I can't figure this out, everything I have tried inside the Sum() function doesn't compile.

Thanks

Comment: First post the exception. Second, EF Core isn't magic. It generates a single SQL query that returns all results. If one error occurs, the query fails. What is the *actual* SQL query?

Comment: Have you turned off client-side evaluation? It's possible that the overcomplicated query (a sum inside a sum?) forces EF Core to load partial results and try to calculate some of the aggregations on the client. Besides, what's the point of storing an invalid `ExchangeRate` ? If there's no exchange rate, the value should be either 1 (for local currency) or NULL (missing exchange rate). If you want to store magic numbers in the database you need to explicitly take care of them in the query

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have provided the requested information.

The reason the Exchange Rate is invalid is that the data has been imported by a 3rd party system, which we cannot control. I'm aware I need to take care of this inside our query, I'm just trying to figure out the best way to handle this.

Comment: That's not the full query (the outer SELECT is missing some fields and the outer SUM) but shows what's wrong. In order to calculate the nested SUMs, EF Core generated a query that aggregates invoice items and an outer query that calculates the final SUM.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why the nested sums? If you wanted to SUM a specific tenant's InvoiceItems you should start from `InvoiceItem`, not `Invoice`. Eg `db.InvoiceItems.Where(i=>i.Invoice.OwnedBy.TenantID=.....)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 
That is the entire SQL query that shows in the output from a single call of this line.

However, I'm not sure why it was decided to go via the Invoices and not the InvoiceItems, as the code was written by another member of the team (I'm just tasked with resolving the issue as a whole), going from the items seems like a better idea to me.

Do you know how I can handle the divide by zero in the sum?

Comment: Use `InvoiceItems` or a raw query. ORMs aren't meant for reporting queries, they're meant to Map Objects. LINQ makes it easier but what you tried is complex enough that the resulting query is problematic. It's easier to write the SQL query than try to guess what LINQ query would map to the SQL you want.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Could you write this up as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: In this case, the LINQ query starts from Invoice, so that has to be the outer query. The values in the `Select` clause (that's what Sum does) come only from InvoiceItems, which means this becomes a subquery in the `Select` clause. You only need the `InvoiceItems` table though, filtered by `Invoice`'s tenant. That's why you need to use `InvoiceItems` as the start

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, EF is not well suitable for complex queries. But this one is doable.

```cs
var query = 
  from z in DatabaseContext.Invoice
  from y in z.Items
  where z.OwnedBy.TenantId == CurrentTenant.TenantId && z.Posted == false
  select new 
  {
     Value = y.ExchangeRate == 0 || y.Units.PriceFactor == 0 
       ? 0 
       : (y.PricePerUnit / y.ExchangeRate) * y.Quantity / y.Units.PriceFactor
  }

MyInsights.UnpostedInvoiceValue = query.Sum(x => x.Value);
```